# What is a Brownian motion with initial distribution $\mu$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The standard Brownian motion $B_t$ starts in $0$. Of course, we can add a drift $x$ so that $B_t +x$ starts in $x$ instead. I read in many papers the terms "Brownian motion with initial distribution $\mu$".

Clearly, the standard Brownian motion $B_t$ is the Brownian motion with initial distribution $\delta_0$ and $B_t +x$  is the Brownian motion with initial distribution $\delta_x$.

But what does "Brownian motion with initial distribution $\mu$" means when $\mu$ is not a Dirac measure ? What is the definition ? I am tempted to say $X_t$ is a "Brownian motion with initial distribution $\mu$" if $X_t=B_t + X$ and $X\sim \mu$, $X$ independent of $B_t$. Any insight ?

Comment: That's it. Just a remark : when you start the Brownian from x, you are just shifting the curve by $x$ vertically. *This is not a drift.* A Brownian motion with drift is the process $(B_t + kt)$ for some constant $k$.